# Spring Jackson Databind does not work for my Kotlin data class

Tags: spring, kotlin, jackson

When using Spring's RestTemplate to deserialize some JSON response into an object I fail to do so because I use a Kotlin data class as my object model.

This is the data class:

```
data class Description (
        val descriptionShort: String,
        val descriptionLong: String,
        val productGroupName: String,
        val shortDescriptionProductGroup: String,
        val descriptionProductGroupMarketing: String
)
```

I using these dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
        //others
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.0.RELEASE")
            //others
        }
        dependencies {
            dependency("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-reactive:2.2.1.RELEASE")
            dependency("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.10.2")
            //others

        }
    }
```

The error message when executing unit tests that involves the RestTemplate logic:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.company.importer.customer.converter.ut.Description` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

Answer (score 2):

A friend told me a no-arg constructor is needed.
This is done in Kotlin by giving every property a default value:

```
data class Description (
        val descriptionShort: String = "",
        val descriptionLong: String = "",
        val productGroupName: String = "",
        val shortDescriptionProductGroup: String = "",
        val descriptionProductGroupMarketing: String = ""
)
```

Comment: No need for that if you're using the `jackson-module-kotlin`.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem many days ago; as first step, I solved the problem as in the response by @xetra11, but I was not very happy with the idea of having default values for technical reasons only.

Finally I solved my issue simply adding the `@RequestBody` annotation to the controller's method parameter: my method now looks like

```
fun newTransaction(@RequestBody input: NewTxRequest)
```

`NewTxRequest` is defined as follows

```
data class NewTxRequest(val from: String, val to: String, val amount: BigDecimal)
```

and the serialization works fine... I hope this can help you, too!

Comment: interesting but unfortunately my logic is not using a controller but a http client and therefore I have no way using @RequestBody

Comment: Can you show the code which you are doing deserialization with?

Comment: ```      final ResponseEntity<Description> exchange = restTemplate
              .exchange(EVALUATE_PRODUCT_PATH + catalogId, HttpMethod.POST, request, Description.class);```

Answer (score 0):

In order for Jackson to correctly handle Kotlin's data classes, you need to add the "[jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin)" dependency.

In the default configuration, `spring-web` automatically configures the Kotlin module if the dependency is present in the classpath.

If you create an `ObjectMapper` manually, you must add the `KotlinModule` to it manually. For example by calling the extension Function `registerKotlinModule()` on the `ObjectMapper` instance.